# Short story involving wearable computers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story a number of years ago (2000-2008) that involved a character wearing a computer like a crown on their head. They were able to query searches and know the results, and I think I also remember there being some description of a map-like program where they were able to look down at their location from the sky and routes would appear from their location to their destination.

I've looked through similar questions posted here and didn't find anything like it. It's not "Norbert and the System". I think I remember the main character being a woman?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're describing real life

Comment: I know humanity is pretty close to having this kind of technology, but I specifically remember the computer being a ring-shaped crown the user would wear.

Comment: Do you remember where you read it, IE if it was online or in a magazine?

Comment: I doubt I would have read it in print, so it was probably online somewhere. I've been on Reddit since 2006, so it could have been from there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The "computer as a crown" reminds me of the ROM from Spider Robinson's novel *Time Pressure*.

The character with the crown was sent back in time as a pilot test for a system that was intended to eventually save the entire human race, from the beginning up to the point time travel was invented (no need after that, they just save people as they live).  The crown connected directly to her brain, but when she first arrived she had amnesia due to an unforeseen collision on arrival (came out in the same place as a big tree).

In an early scene, the narrator character notices the traveler getting more and more agitated, and realizes it's because she's never had coffee before; hence the caffeine is having much stronger effects, with less ability to compensate, than it would in him or any of his contemporaries.

Comment: I don't think this was it. I'm fairly certain it was a short story, something very brief.